# Visibility effects of synchronization in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, visibility

[This](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/LCK10-J.+Use+a+correct+form+of+the+double-checked+locking+idiom) article says:

> In this noncompliant code example, the Helper class is made immutable
>   by declaring its fields final. The JMM guarantees that immutable
>   objects are fully constructed before they become visible to any other
>   thread. The block synchronization in the getHelper() method guarantees
>   that all threads that can see a non-null value of the helper field
>   will also see the fully initialized Helper object.

```
public final class Helper {
  private final int n;

  public Helper(int n) {
    this.n = n;
  }

  // Other fields and methods, all fields are final
}

final class Foo {
  private Helper helper = null;

  public Helper getHelper() {
    if (helper == null) {            // First read of helper
      synchronized (this) {
        if (helper == null) {        // Second read of helper
          helper = new Helper(42);
        }
      }
    }

    return helper;                   // Third read of helper
  }
}
```

> However, this code is not guaranteed to succeed on all Java Virtual
>   Machine platforms because there is no happens-before relationship
>   between the first read and third read of helper. Consequently, it is
>   possible for the third read of helper to obtain a stale null value
>   (perhaps because its value was cached or reordered by the compiler),
>   causing the getHelper() method to return a null pointer.

I don't know what to make of it. I can agree that there is no happens before relationship between first and third read, at least no **immediate** relationship. Isn't there a transitive happens-before relationship in a sense that first read must happen before second, and that second read has to happen before third, therefore first read has to happen before third

Could someone elaborate more proficiently?

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZZYK.jpg) is what basically multithreading is. There's no guarantee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no transitive relationship.

The idea behind the JMM is to define rules that JVM must respect. Providing the JVM follows these rules, they are authorized to reorder and execute code as they want.

In your example, the 2nd read and the 3rd read are not related - no memory barrier introduced by the use of `synchronized` or `volatile` for example.  Thus, the JVM is allowed to execute it as follow:

```
 public Helper getHelper() {
    final Helper toReturn = helper;  // "3rd" read, reading null
    if (helper == null) {            // First read of helper
      synchronized (this) {
        if (helper == null) {        // Second read of helper
          helper = new Helper(42);
        }
      }
    }

    return toReturn; // Returning null
  }
```

Your call would then return a null value. Yet, a singleton value would have been created. However, sub-sequent calls may still get a null value.

As suggested, using a volatile would introduce new memory barrier. Another common solution is to capture the read value and return it.

```
 public Helper getHelper() {
    Helper singleton = helper;
    if (singleton == null) {
      synchronized (this) {
        singleton = helper;
        if (singleton == null) {
          singleton = new Helper(42);
          helper = singleton;
        }
      }
    }

    return singleton;
  }
```

As your rely on a local variable, there is nothing to reorder. Everything is happening in the same thread.

Comment: Thanks, I am surprised there is no happens before relation across synchronized block. It seems so subtle and error prone. I'll have to be so much more careful not to fall into this pit.

Comment: so just to make it sure, if helper was to be made volatile this code would no longer be buggy as volatile read/write introduces happens-before with variables before/after volatile access which synchronized doesn't. I know that reads/writes to all variables before volatile write are not allowed to be reordered to occur after volatile write. Similar goes for volatile read where all variables reads/writes are not allowed to be reordered before the volatile read. In this sense volatile is more strict then synchronized because it creates a stronger barrier

Comment: I am not sure we can really compare `synchronized` and `volatile` this way. With synchorized, whatever happens in the block will be visible to any next synchronized block on the same element - reads or writes. With volatile, it will depend on the operation: reading a volatile element sets a read barrier, writing into a volatile element sets a write barrier. In a way, `volatile` is more flexible than `synchronized`. But `synchronized` is easier to manage many elements at once - all ops in the block - while `volatile` would require you to read the element even if not wanted.

Comment: if you wouldn't mind, I've opened a separate question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806674/synchronized-reordering-in-java). It may not be directly connected to this problem

Comment: I would just bring your attention to this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/52806923/5182723) which suggests that there is a happens before relation between 1st and 3rd read because synchronized imposes a barrier. Could you comment on this?

Comment: This is a different case. In the other question, only writes can move into or before the synchronized block. And reads can move into or after the block - always providing that they do not appear inside the block. In your case, the "3rd" read is move before the block, a legal operation.

Comment: to my understanding there is a read-acquire barrier at the start of the synchronized block and definition of the read-acquire barrier is: "A read-acquire executes before all reads and writes by the same thread that follow it in program order". Specifically, having a read-acquire barrier forbids third read to occur before the start of the synchronized block. Could you reflect on this?

Comment: Also, JLS states that: "If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y)". From this I read that there is a happens before between write to the helper and third read. A thread cannot set a value to a non-null reference and then observe that reference to be null

Comment: Yes, but the problem here is the if-block, that introduces an alternative block. Sadly, I cannot quote the right JLS or JMM paragraph for this.

Comment: I have presented my case more thoroughly in the comments section of the linked article(https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/LCK10-J.+Use+a+correct+form+of+the+double-checked+locking+idiom?focusedCommentId=133071133#comment-133071133).

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no any transitive relationship between those reads. `synchornized` only guarantees visibility of changes that were made within synchronized blocks of the same lock. In this case all reads do not use the synchronized blocks on the same lock, hence this is flawed and visibility is not guaranteed.

Because there is no locking once the field is initialized, it is critical that the field be declared `volatile`. This will ensure the visibility.

```
private volatile Helper helper = null;
```

Comment: The only time when this would possibly be a bug is when thread finds null reference on the first read and then returns null even after entering the synchronized block. Could you please give an example of a visibility bug for this code?

Comment: @MarinVeršić There are visibility issues in common path which occurs after the initialization of the field. You may read a stale value which is obvious.

Comment: I see that there is an unprotected access to the variable. But it isn't quite obvious to me that is a bug in this example. From my point of view, there could only be visibility issue if third read occurred before the first read. Isn't this true?

Comment: @MarinVeršić what is interesting is that if we think of `synchronized` like a barrier, those reads should not be able to float across that barrier, I don't think this answer has all the details needed

Comment: Thank @Eugene, I would just like a more detailed explanation how a stale read can occur in this case

Comment: @MarinVeršić your other comment about these two answers to both your questions is summarized in my previous comment, I will try to come with an answer to these later. It seems you tend to think that because there is a barrier, the third read should not be able to float around...

Comment: yes, exactly. You immediately figured out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It's all explained here https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_singletons_and_singleton_factories, the issue simple.

> ... Notice that we do several reads of instance in this code, and at
>   least "read 1" and "read 3" are the reads without any
>   synchronization ... Specification-wise, as mentioned in happens-before
>   consistency rules, a read action can observe the unordered write via
>   the race. This is decided for each read action, regardless what other
>   actions have already read the same location. In our example, that
>   means that even though "read 1" could read non-null instance, the code
>   then moves on to returning it, then it does another racy read, and it
>   can read a null instance, which would be returned!

Comment: this is where I learned the pattern. Thanks for posting the link.