# Synchronized reordering in java

Tags: java, synchronized

It is known that JVM shouldn't reorder statements from withing synchronized block to outside of the synchronized block. Considering this, is JVM allowed to reorder assignment `y = 7` to occur after the `synchronized` block in the following snippet?

```
x = 5;
y = 7;
synchronized (this) {
    x = 6;
}
```

We know that variable assignment before the synchronized block can be reordered to occur inside the block. So the following should be valid reordering of the initial code:

```
x = 5;
synchronized (this) {
    x = 6;
    y = 7;
}
```

One could argue that, because this is a valid ordering, `y` assignment cannot occur after the `synchronized` block as it would violate the rule that code from within synchronized block mustn't be reordered to occur after the block and deduce that `y` **happens-before end** of the synchronized block.

On the other hand, it could be that all orderings are not equivalent and it matters which ordering was the actual ordering. Specifically, if `y` assignment was originally done within the synchronized block it couldn't occur after the block, otherwise it could.

To sum up, is next ordering valid ordering of the first snippet?

```
x = 5;
synchronized (this) {
    x = 6;
}
y = 7;
```

Comment: Having roamed through the Internet I got pretty sure my reasoning here is flawed

Comment: The code snippets in their current form look like `x` and `y` are method-local variables, even though you probably meant that they are non-private fields accessible to multiple threads?

Comment: yes, I wasn't aware of it, I've fixed the example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JLS 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> - If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).
>
> ...
>
> - If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).

Your question only makes sense when including the assumption that the value of `y` could be visible outside the current thread. If that's the case, the combination of these two rules requires that the assignment not be reordered after the synchronized block.

Comment: well yes, but this is for a *single* thread; the OP really meant that `y` is shared, in my understanding

Comment: @Eugene That's what I meant by "the assumption". The second bullet point is what links this thread to other threads.

Comment: @chrylis right, in such a case since the OP confirmed that `y` is shared just now, you might want to update your answer to reflect exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your reasoning are flawed; this can not happen.

A monitor enter is like a `volatile load` (not entirely correct, but I understand it simpler like that - there will be two barriers inserted : `LoadLoad|LoadStore`) and operations that are *before* that can not float across that barrier.

I am pretty sure, this is specified by the `JLS` and while I wanted to link to that, the other answer has already did - go upvote it.

Comment: you do see how this links to my previous question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805020/visibility-effects-of-synchronization-in-java/52805671#52805671)? Current consensus there is that third read can occur before the synchronized block, although it differs in the sense that it depends on the first read if synchronized block is executed

Comment: I don't think I can accept both of these answers at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me, I was referring to @chrylis answer to this question and the Kineolyan answer on my other question. I don't think they can both be correct. I did upvote both